# What is the difference between Disallow: /? and Disallow: /*?* in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

We have many parameters in our URL and I wonder what will do the parameters pasted below. Will they disallow all the parameters after `?`? Please tell me what does this mean:

```
Disallow: /?
Disallow: /*?*
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Instance 1

```
Disallow: /?
```

This will disallow any URL's where `?` follows a `/`.

For example:-

```
http://www.example.net/?
http://www.example.net/page/?
http://www.example.net/page/sub/?
http://www.example.net/page/sub/?89y398th03th
```

### Instance 2

```
Disallow: */?
```

This will disallow any URL's where `?` exists in the URL after a `/`:-

```
http://www.example.net/?
http://www.example.net/page/?
http://www.example.net/page/sub/?
http://www.example.net/page/sub/?89y398th03th
http://www.example.net/search?q=url
http://www.example.net/type?paramater=query
```

You would benefit from reading the [robotstxt documentation](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) where all of this is explained.

Comment: `Disallow: /?` will only disallow URLs in the root of the site (prefix matching). ie. `example.net/?something`, but not `http://www.example.net/page/?` (you would need a pattern like `*/?` for that to work). (The `*` at the end of the pattern in `/*?*` is also superfluous.)